# Values not calculating in Userform

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, userform, calculated-field

Can someone please help me.

I have a userform which has a number of numeric fields. The issue is that my Total box will not calculate them as it is recognising a number as text. So for example if I was to say HE.Value (10) + ME.Value (10) for example should = 20 however is the Total is coming to 1010. and if I * it instead I am receiving an error to debug as it recognises the value as text format.

I have never had this issue in a userform before. Is someone able to assist please?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to cast your strings as numeric e.g. try `CINT(ME.VALUE)` if these are integers or `CLNG(ME.VALUE)` if they have decimal places

Comment: @MiguelH Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of that. Excellent thanks for the answer

Comment: You might also be interested in this ..http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/validate-numbers.htm

Comment: @MiguelH `CLng` converts to a `Long`, which is a 32-bit integer type (i.e. doesn't have decimals). If you need decimals you use `CDec` to get a `Decimal`, `CDbl` to get a `Double`, or `CSng` to get a `Single`, keeping in mind that floating-point rounding errors are more likely on `Single` and `Double` types, depending on what you end up doing with the converted numbers.

Comment: @Mat'sMug oops! .. a little a bit of PEBCAK on my part! Of course it is 'CDec' :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
totalBox.Text = box1.Text + box2.Text
```

When the two operands are `String`, the `+` operator works as a string concatenation operator, meaning it works exactly like the `&` operator. That's how you get `1010` instead of `20`: VBA thinks you're asking it to *concatenate* strings.

VBA cannot do arithmetics on strings, so if your strings *represent* numeric values, you need to convert them first.

If you're only working with integers then you can do this with the `CLng` type conversion function:

```
totalBox.Text = CStr(CLng(box1.Text) + CLng(box2.Text))
```

Notice this makes the back-to-string conversion explicit (`CStr`); leave it out and VBA will perform that type conversion implicitly.

Comment: @A.S.H that's probably correct, too lazy to check, edited... damn implicit type conversions all over the place...